# Tools similar to Google BITE = Browser Integrated Testing Environment and in browser manual testing aids?

Tags: manual-testing, action-recording

I read through [How Google Tests Software](http://books.google.ee/books/about/How_Google_Tests_Software.html?id=vHlTOVTKHeUC) and was quite curious about the [BITE project](https://code.google.com/p/bite-project/).  The main idea is to reduce friction in manual testing by allowing the following to be done without leaving the browser

- record bugs directly to a bug database
- automatically take a screenshot of page where bug is found
- save the HTML of the page
- have the steps to generate the bug automatically recorded
- display bugs already reported on the page (to reduce repeat testing)

It doesn't look like this BITE project is still under [very active development](https://code.google.com/p/bite-project/source/list) or widely used which makes me question if it's a good avenue to look into (and spend valuable time going through the set-up proccess).  Does anyone have experience with tools that have similar functionality?

I am the only person on QA in a small startup mainly focused on a Single Page javascript application. I'm spend most of my time in a SET'ish roll focused on aiding developement and code oriented automated tests. It tends to be spare time of project managers and other not-so-technical people used to quickly find bugs with click-around manual tests.  I would find a tool like this very valuable in producing technically useful information in adhoc testing session.

Comment: Last commits to the project were on Apr 22, 2013. Why do you thing it is not under active development?

Comment: My bad, I should rephrase it to not under very active development or widely used.  I think the point of the question was more to figure out if this kind of concept is useful in general to anyone outside of Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not fit all the criteria you mention, but I like qTrace, although it does not help you keep track of test cases you can record your actions while you are going through the test cases and then automatically generate a bug report.  The program not only records the steps, it also takes screenshots of every step and adds icons that indicate what was done on the page.  Additionally you can edit the picture, for example add a red box around a specific area on the screenshot.  Another nice feature is it's integration with software like JIRA and other defect tracking software, it however does not automatically figure out if the bug is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com/) on one of our projects that handles about half of what you asked for:

1. It records bugs directly to a bug database (or where-ever you point it to)
2. Automatically takes a screenshot of page where bug is found

It doesn't save the HTML of the page but it does take record some of the reporters info like:

- IP address
- Email address
- Screen resolution
- Browser type (including OS)
- Browser size (resolution)

It's a paid application but I like it a lot and it certainly gives the users, programmers and myself enough of a head start that I prefer filing bugs through it (when I can).

Answer (score 0):

It does look like BITE isn't being actively developed, unfortunately.

If you're working in a Microsoft environment, Microsoft Test Manager offers the features you're looking for - but it's tied to an environment with MS Team Foundation Server, where TFS is used as the bug tracking system.

I'm not aware of anything else that offers this level of support for manual testing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Mozilla Moztrap. While it doesn't support all the features you're looking for, it's a useful tool for manual testing, and since it's open source you could fork the project and build in the features you'd like. 
https://github.com/mozilla/moztrap